# Combining polygons based on distance matrix in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, point, merge, polygon-creation

I have the following layers in QGIS:

- a polygon layer made up of all the zip-code areas in Germany
- a layer displaying all the electricity grid nodes in the country.

In a previous step, I created a distance matrix to connect all zip-codes (or their centroids to be more precise) to their closest grid node.

Is there a way to combine all those polygons belonging to a single grid node (nearest point in the distance matrix) into one?

The result would be the area every single grid node is covering.

Comment: You already did most of the work. Just ensure to assign a unique attribute of the closest node to the polygons. Then dissolve or merge them by this attribute.

Comment: No idea I was so close to it already, did work wonderfully, thanks